# How to make the serial number auto generation stable and fixed if the sorting is done in ascending order in some other column in the gridview

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, listview

I have a list view in my page.I have three columns like serial number,row name,row code.I have did sorting(ascending order) using jquery for the row name.If that sorting is made mean my serial number also changing,yup it obviously change and i need to fix the number stable and default 1,2,3 in my list view if i sort also.Help me out! please help me to fix the serial number fixed, it should continue 1,2,3..so on if i sort also .I have tried some jquery but it was not working in that.How to use the jquery function to fix this issue?

```
My view :
@model List<BusinessEntities.RoleChangeReasonModel>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr class="table-primary">
                <th></th>
                <th class="w-1">No.</th>
                <th>row name</th>
                <th class="pointer">row code<i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort-up"></i></th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Action</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           @{ int i=1; }
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                     <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="Id editable" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)" class="checkBoxRow" name="chkRow" /></td>
                  //serial number autogeneration  <td class="sno">@Html.Raw(i++)</td>
                    <td><input class="Id editable" type="hidden" readonly="readonly" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)" /></td>
                    <td><input class="Reason editable" readonly="readonly" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.rowname)" /></td>
<td><input class="Reason editable" readonly="readonly" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.rowcode)" /></td>
                 </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: So you mean you want to “re-index” the serial number row, effectively assigning _new_ serial numbers to the rows, based on their new position after the sorting happened? Then you will likely have to loop over your records, and explicitly set the new value in that column - I doubt any table sorter plugin/library will offer such a functionality by the default.

Comment: Or, if you need this for display purposes only, but don’t need to actually submit that value to the server when you finally submit the form(?) - then you could simply leave the table cells in that row _empty_, and use a CSS counter instead - that can automatically take the _current_ order of the table rows in the DOM into account.

Comment: Thank you @04FS ! I have tried with the CSS counter property but thats not working for  the tag<td> ,as i have the class=" " inside the <td> for my inline editing , i used id=" " for the Counter but it was not working .

Comment: What class? What does an empty(?) ID have to do with CSS counters? Very unclear what you are talking about.

Comment: First of all i thank you for the help .Previously i had written like this <td class="chapter" id=" w1" >,again i added one more inside ,because of that it was not worked .Then i changed everything ,now it was working fine.Thank you so much.Very very thank you sir @04FS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.w=1 {

  counter-reset: counter1;
}

tbody::before {

  counter-increment: counter1;
  content: "Section " counter(counter1) ". ";
} 

View:
 <td><input type="checkbox" id="w-1" class="Id editable" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)" class="checkBoxRow" name="chkRow" /></td>
```